# Balance docker service in docker node groups instead of nodes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have the following problem:

I have a docker service with 2 replicas and 4 workers splitted in 2 different datacenters.

I know when swarm spawns new replicas will do it in a different host each time. Is it possible to configure it to spawn it in different groups of nodes if I label them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can attach labels to nodes, as follows:

```sh
docker node update --label-add region=east worker-1
docker node update --label-add region=east worker-2
docker node update --label-add region=west worker-3
docker node update --label-add region=west worker-4
```

You can then start your service with contraints or placement-prefs:

```sh
# This will force your service to only run on nodes in your 'east' region
docker service create \
    --name myservice-east \
    --replicas 2 \
    --constraint node.labels.region==east \
    yourimage

# This will spread the replicas across the regions:
docker service create \
  --replicas 2 \
  --name spread-service \
  --placement-pref 'spread=node.labels.region' \
  myotherimage
```